# siunitx version v3.0.2: How to typeset \num{10e0.75}

Tags: siunitx

I have problem to typeset `\num{10e0.75}` with `siunitx` version v3.0.2:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}    
  \num{10e0.75}    
\end{document}
```

Package complains:

```
! Package siunitx Error: Invalid number '10e0.75'.
```

Comment: As far as I can see, exponents should be integers. The fact that previously nonintegers were allowed should be considered a “hidden feature”.

Comment: By the way, a minimal example would be `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{siunitx}\begin{document}\num{1e0.75}\end{document}`

Comment: What do you intend, say, `\num{e0.75}` to work out to?

Comment: @Mico: I tested also \num{e0.75}. It doesn't work.

Comment: Of course it doesn’t work. (Well, there’s the `parade-numbers=false` option, but I don’t think you’re interested in that option.) My question to you was, what do *you* expect the output of `\num{e0.75}` (or, if you prefer, `\num{1e0.75}`) to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exponent part of a number must be an integer in order to be parsed. If you want to use `siunitx` features with non-standard numbers, you need to turn off parsing *or* re-define what counts as a 'digit' (the latter will drop the leading `0`).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}    
  \num[input-digits = .0123456789]{10e0.75}
  \num[parse-numbers = false]{10 \times10^{0.75}}
\end{document}
```